# "take a picture," "take a video"

Tags: word-choice

I'm quite certain the following sentence is natural:

> Ikuto was taking a picture of her.

But which of the following would be more common in spoken English?

> Ikuto was recording a video of her.
>
> Ikuto was taking a video of her.

My initial thought was that "recording" was the better choice here. But then I couldn't find evidence to back this up online.

Note that this sentence would be said when describing an illustration of a character named Ikuto recording a video of his friend. Since we have context, there would not be confusion when using "taking." In other words, it's clear that Ikuto isn't doing something like taking a DVD of "her" that was on the table, or anything like that.

Please help!

Comment: As a native speaker with three kids and many, many hours of video recordings, I would use _**recording** a video_ to describe the actual filming (despite no film being involved any more) and _**making** a video_ to describe the process of editing everything into a more finished product (with titles and such).  _**making**_ could also apply to a more involved production with multiple actors and sets and so on.  _**Shooting**_ a video would, to me, mean the same as the latter meaning of _**making**_.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the most natural expression would be, "Ikuto was **taping** her." It sounds perfectly natural to say, ". . .taking a video of her," as well, although it wouldn't be my first choice in speech. If you wanted to use the word "recording," I would say, "Ikuto was recording her."

It mostly comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Is "taping" still relevant with modern-day video recorders, which are typically digital?

I agree that "Ikuto was recording her" sounds natural. Thanks!

Comment: @Niko You could also say **filming her** and nobody would misunderstand.

Comment: @Niko At least where I am from (the Midwest), absolutely. The expression has become idiomatic. No one would think you were using actual magnetic tape. I agree with Jason that filming is also a perfectly natural construction (and similarly, does not carry connotation of being recorded using actual photographic film).

Answer (score 0):

You could also say *shooting a video* or *making a video*.

There is nothing wrong with any of them.

However, if you're looking for what is the most common from among those four, Google Books Ngram Viewer suggests that *making a video* [has the most use](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=recording%20a%20video%2C%20taking%20a%20video%2C%20shooting%20a%20video%2C%20making%20a%20video&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crecording%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctaking%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cshooting%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmaking%20a%20video%3B%2Cc0) in print.

As for spoken English as opposed to written, I don't know. All would be equally understood.

Comment: In my experience, "making a video" refers to something a bit broader. For example, if Ikuto recorded his friend in a variety of different scenes, then combined them into a single video, that whole process is "making a video."

I agree that "shooting a video" is good. Unfortunately, this sentence will be used as a sample answer to an ESL interview test question, and the students might not be familiar with the word "shooting."

Comment: @Niko, agreed- making a video is more about video-editing. If you look at actual instances of "making a video", it's things like "they will be making a video montage" and "Designing a System for Supporting the Process of Making a Video Sequence".